# Xcode view AutoLayout issues

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, lldb

Does anyone know how to view the AutoLayout issues in Xcode's view debugger? In the view hierarchy window, I get the following showing "4 issues" for my button component, but how do I find out what those four issues are? It cannot be clicked on and when I expand the element, none of the child views are showing any issues. I cannot seem to find anything that explains how to find out what the four issues are.

[image]

Comment: They are in the Debug Navigator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see this warning icon:

[image]

You should also see a purple warning Triangle icon at the top:

[image]

Depending on the issue, you may also see the explanation in the Inspector pane:

[image]

---

**Edit**

Apparently, View Debug Hierarchy in `Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)` has some bugs.

In this example:

[image]

Label "V1" has only a Top constraint -- hovering over the Warning Icon shows the correct information.

Label "V2" is configured with a layer shadow... hovering over the icon ***should*** tell me *"The layer is using dynamic shadows which are expensive to render..."*, but instead simply shows *"4 issues"* with no way to **see** those issues.

Also, there is no longer a purple icon in the top navigation bar...

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case, at least not on Version 14.2 (14C18) (current latest version). There's no purple warning triangle icon at the top, there's other warnings (unrelated issues).

Comment: @internetdotcom - curious... Clearly a bug in `Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)` that should be reported to Apple.